# Docker redownloading base image at each deploy (heroku.yml)

Tags: deployment, heroku, node.js, cache, docker

My [build logs](https://gist.github.com/JakubKoralewski/3824a160a8b51a7467be232bd9130f2a), but the important bit below:

```
aac6a114e757: Pull complete
    Digest: sha256:48b6801235e4179dec2427bd57853239553ea8bba20fba496df219469370b11c
    Status: Downloaded newer image for mhart/alpine-node:15
     ---> 53438cdc4c73
    Step 2/11 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Running in 7346b7cbd272
    Removing intermediate container 7346b7cbd272
     ---> d6b90bc0c19b
    Step 3/11 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
     ---> eeb7183c29f1
    Step 4/11 : RUN npm i
     ---> Running in adb2f082e16d
```

For some reason at each deploy I get this: `Status: Downloaded newer image for mhart/alpine-node:15`, as if that download wasn't cached.
Also, despite not changing the contents of package.json or package-lock.jon the command `npm i` gets re-run. [But in the same run, I believe the release phase is cached though (the release phase uses the builder stage from the `Dockerfile`)](https://gist.github.com/JakubKoralewski/3824a160a8b51a7467be232bd9130f2a#file-herokubuild-log-L144-L176)

My [Dockerfile](https://github.com/JakubKoralewski/lets-watch-it-together/blob/7b9ccc670842d5678d785caff555458d47f77aff/Dockerfile)
My [heroku.yml](https://github.com/JakubKoralewski/lets-watch-it-together/blob/7b9ccc670842d5678d785caff555458d47f77aff/heroku.yml)
My [app.json](https://github.com/JakubKoralewski/lets-watch-it-together/blob/7b9ccc670842d5678d785caff555458d47f77aff/app.json)

I don't know why this is. I am confused because also for Heroku to recognise my app as a container based deploy I had to do `heroku container:push web` for my app, would that interfere somehow with `heroku.yml` based deployment?